# Unresponsive image on Next JS@13.0.0 when using Image from next/image with tailwindcss class

Tags: javascript, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to make my image responsive on mobile view. I've been to set Image className with tailwindcss classes, and its work when I only use reactjs or regular img tag.
I want to make [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rIfr.png) responsive.
I've been try to set **layout** attribute of Image with "responsive" but the image disapear. I've been try to set with "fill" but it's too big and flat, actually it really "fill" my entire screen

This is my code

```
<div className="flex justify-center lg:items-end lg:justify-end">
    <Image
      className="pt-[45px] lg:pt-0 w-[219px] h-[222px] ss:w-[271px] ss:h-[276px] sm:w-[379px] sm:h-[382px] lg:w-[421px] lg:h-[426px] z-[1]"
      src={data?.image}
      alt="person_hero"
      width="421"
      height="426"
    />
</div>
```

**I have found the way**
In NextJS v13.0.0, the image should be wrapped in your responsive code. don't place your responsive className on Nextjs Image component directly.

this is code solved my problem.

```
    <div className="pt-[45px] lg:pt-0 w-[219px] h-[222px] ss:w-[271px] ss:h-[276px] sm:w-[379px] sm:h-[382px] lg:w-[421px] lg:h-[426px] z-[1]">
      <Image src={data?.image} alt="person_hero" width="421" height="426" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Not only for tailwindcss but also CSS, Module CSS or something else for element styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have found the way**
The image should be wrapped in your responsive code. don't place your responsive className on Nextjs Image component directly.

this is code solved the problem.

```
    <div className="pt-[45px] lg:pt-0 w-[219px] h-[222px] ss:w-[271px] ss:h-[276px] sm:w-[379px] sm:h-[382px] lg:w-[421px] lg:h-[426px] z-[1]">
      <Image src={data?.image} alt="person_hero" width="421" height="426" />
    </div>
```